# noodles is delicious vs noodles are delicious

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What's the correct way of saying 'Noodles is/are the most delicious food'?
If we refer to noodles as a dish may we use 'is' in this case, then we should use it with 'the' I guess, but 'The noodles is the most delicious food' sounds weird for me, or is it?
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only heard and seen "Noodles **are** delicious." or "The noodles are really good, thank you!" So for you, it would be "Noodles (no article because we are talking about noodles in general) are the most delicious food." If you're talking about some particular noodles, it would be "The noodles are delicious." We are talking about the plural of noodle - noodles.

Comment: Though, oddly, _spaghetti_, which is plural in Italian, is treated as uncountable in English, as though 'it' were a substance.

Comment: @KateBunting - similarly with paparazzi, people seem to no longer acknowledge a single paparazzo. Data/datum similarly. You could stretch to "This Korean chicken and noodles is delicious" by kind of mentally clumping them together into being a single dish, rather than a plural of individual foodstuffs.

Comment: In AmE *noodles* is not a dish (i.e. a specific type of meal).  A four year-old might tell you they're having noodles for dinner but adults generally do not say things like, *I had noodles for dinner.*  Noodles are usually a component of a larger dish and we say we ate the larger dish.  I ate spaghetti.  I ate ramen.  I ate Korean chicken and noodles.  I ate linguini and clams.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the noodles themselves requires a plural verb:

- Noodles *are* the main ingredient.
- The noodles *are* in the cupboard.

Using a short form for, say, Singapore noodles or egg noodles with Alfredo sauce, where the listeners know what it is referring to, requires a singular verb:

- Noodles *is* my favourite meal.

Saying "the noodles is" would be unusual, as with the "the" it wouldn't simply be a short form.